# Stop on exception Delphi 10.1

Tags: delphi, debugging, exception

I have recently moved from Delphi 7 to 10.1 Berlin.

I am used to being shown the line where an exception is raised in Delphi7 but the new IDE doesn't seem to work the same.   I am just getting the exception notification followed by termination of my application when I close the exception box.

I have searched the options for a 'Stop on exception' checkbox (like Delphi 7) but cannot find it.

This is a fire monkey application by the way

Peter

Comment: Did you configurate it as debug? Did you maybe use _start without debugger_ (green arrow), which looks quite similar to older versions _start_?

Comment: Yes I did.   It stops at breakpoints but an exception doesn't stop it

Comment: Are you aware that there are *two* "Run"-Buttons on the toolbar now and the one that looks the same as in Delphi 7 starts the program *without* the debugger?

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the option called [Stop on Delphi Exceptions](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32015) within Delphi 7, its current equivalent is called *Notify on Language Exceptions* and is located via [Tools > Options > Debugger Options > Embarcadero Debuggers > Language Exceptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Language_Exceptions).

[image: Tools > Options > Debugger Options > Embarcadero Debuggers > Language Exceptions]

Futhermore, I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020561/how-to-disable-all-exception-raising-in-delphi).

Comment: Thanks,  that was already checked but I have found the cause of the problem on the same page.   The error I was trying to trap was listed as one of the ones to ignore so as soon as I unchecked that error type I was able to get the program to break and show me the line where the error occurred